# Example of an infinite sum of functions $f_n(x)$ that converges to $x$, is there a typo in my book?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

I have a book that says the following:

> Let $f_1(x), f_2(x), \dotsc$ a sequence of bounded functions with $f_1(x) + f_2(x) + \dotsb = x$, for example
>   $$
>  f_1(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}, \;
>  f_n(x) = \frac{\sin xn}{xn} - \frac{\sin (n-1)x}{(n-1)x}
> $$

However,
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} +
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(
 \frac{\sin(xn)}{xn}-\frac{\sin(x (n-1))}{x(n-1)}
\right)
 = 0.
$$
 So is there an error or typo in the book and if so, what do you think the book meant to say? Or am I somehow misinterpreting what it says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided $\sin x n \ne 0$ for any $n\in N$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{m\to \infty}(\sin m x)/m x=0$ as you said. You are right. The book has an error,maybe a typo.

Comment: What would be an example of a sequence of (bounded) functions such that f1(x)+f2(x)+⋯=x?

Comment: Let $f_1(x)=x$ for  $|x|\leq 1;$ and $ f_1(x)=0$ for $ |x|>1.$  For $n>1$ let $f_n(x)=x$ for $n<|x|\leq n+1;$  and $f_n(x)=0$  for $ (|x|\leq n \lor |x|>n+1).$